# Laravel - Adding Data to multiple tables with one insert Form

Tags: laravel

Hello I'm trying to insert data in 3 tables at the same time but I dono why it's not working. This is the insert function

```js
 public function ProductStore(Request $request)
    {
        $image = $request->file('product_thumbnail');
        $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($image)->save('upload/products/thumbnail/' . $name_gen);
        $save_url = 'upload/products/thumbnail/' . $name_gen;

        $product_id = Product::insertGetId([
            'brand_id' => $request->brand_id,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'subcategory_id' => $request->subcategory_id,
            'subsubcategory_id' => $request->subsubcategory_id,
            'product_name' => $request->product_name,
            'product_slug' =>  strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $request->product_name)),
            'product_code' => $request->product_code,
            'product_quantity' => $request->product_quantity,

            'selling_price' => $request->selling_price,
            'discount_price' => $request->discount_price,
            'short_description' => $request->short_description,
            'long_description' => $request->long_description,
            'specifications' => $request->specifications,

            'hot_deal' => $request->hot_deal,
            'featured' => $request->featured,
            'special_offer' => $request->special_offer,
            'special_deal' => $request->special_deal,

            'product_thumbnail' => $save_url,
            'status' => 1,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);


       
        $images = $request->file('multi_img');
        foreach ($images as $img) {
          
            $multi_img_name = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($img)->save('upload/products/multi-image/' . $multi_img_name);
            $uploadPath = 'upload/products/multi-image/' . $multi_img_name;

            MultiImg::insert([
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'photo_name' => $uploadPath,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
        }

        if ($request->subsubcategory_id == 1) {
            ProductLaptop::insert([
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'laptop_os' => $request->laptop_os,
                'laptop_cpu' => $request->laptop_cpu,
                'laptop_gpu' => $request->laptop_gpu,
                'laptop_memory' => $request->laptop_memory,
                'laptop_display' => $request->laptop_display,
                'laptop_storage' => $request->laptop_storage,
            ]);
        } else if ($request->subsubcategory_id == 2) {
            ProductTablet::insert([
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'tablet_os' => $request->tablet_os,
                'tablet_cpu' => $request->tablet_cpu,
                'tablet_memory' => $request->tablet_memory,
                'tablet_display' => $request->tablet_display,
                'tablet_storage' => $request->tablet_storage,
                'tablet_camera' => $request->tablet_camera,
            ]);
        } else if ($request->subsubcategory_id == 3) {
            ProductPhone::insert([
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'phone_os' => $request->phone_os,
                'phone_cpu' => $request->phone_cpu,
                'phone_memory' => $request->phone_memory,
                'phone_display' => $request->phone_display,
                'phone_storage' => $request->phone_storage,
                'phone_camera' => $request->phone_camera,
            ]);
        }
```

As you can see I am trying to add data in a products table, a multimages table and then based on the subsubcategory_id selected in the form either in laptops or tablets or phones table.

The first two work as in it inserts correctly in the products and multimages table with product_id in multimage table matching the id in product table....but the if conditional insert doesn't work. When I hit the submit button the page just refreshes and no data in inserted in any of the tables.

Comment: Have you checked that `$request->subsubcategory_id` is indeed populated with the values you're expecting?

Comment: A dd(request->all) before the insert function. https://imgur.com/a/5Df0e4Y. But I recall a dd() inside the function didn't work so the request data is ok but it doesn't enter the function? Any ideas why?